# Error after upgrading to 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

After upgrading from 5.1 to 5.2 I'm getting this error on some of my pages.. I'm not sure what is causing this?

```
ErrorException in RouteServiceProvider.php line 29: Missing argument 2 for App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::App\Providers{closure}()
```

This happens when I for example try to login.

Any ideas?

From stack:

```
1. in RouteServiceProvider.php line 29
2. at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'Missing argument 2 for App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::App\Providers{closure}()', 'Z:\development\wamp\www\larabook\Laravel\app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php', '29', array('sql' => object(QueryExecuted))) in RouteServiceProvider.php line 29
3. at RouteServiceProvider->App\Providers{closure}(object(QueryExecuted))
4. at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array(object(QueryExecuted))) in Dispatcher.php line 221
5. at Dispatcher->fire(object(QueryExecuted)) in Connection.php line 750
```

Line 29. in RouteServiceProvider.php (first line below):

```
   \DB::listen(function($sql,$bindings,$time) {

        $sql = str_replace(array('%', '?'), array('%%', '%s'), $sql);
        $sql = vsprintf($sql, $bindings);

        $time_now = (new \DateTime)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');;
        $log = $time_now.' | '.$sql.' | '.$time.'ms'.PHP_EOL;
        \Storage::append('logs\query.log', $log);

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        \DB::listen(function($query) {

        $sql = str_replace(array('%', '?'), array('%%', '%s'), $query->sql);
        $sql = vsprintf($sql, $query->bindings);

        $time_now = (new \DateTime)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');;
        $log = $time_now.' | '.$sql.' | '.$query->time.'ms'.PHP_EOL;
        \Storage::append('logs\query.log', $log);

    });
```

Found the solution. Apparently you need to pass in an object now instead of those 3 parameters I used previously.